Async wrapper - Pylance doesn't recognize that the function is now awaitable
For convenience, I created a wrapper to run blocking code in a separate thread.
from functools import wraps
import time
import asyncio

def async_wrapper(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapper")
        return await asyncio.to_thread(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@async_wrapper
def blocking_code():
    print("Start")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("end")

await blocking_code() # type issue

wrapper
Start
end

However, Pylance shows the following warning (in VSCode, python 3.10):
"None" is not awaitable
  "None" is incompatible with protocol "Awaitable[_T_co@Awaitable]"
    "__await__" is not present PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(function) def blocking_code() -> None

Is there a way to fix the type hinting?
(This is to avoid having to create a public async function that simply calls a private blocking function each time.)
Edit:

{
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict"
}

After enabling strict mode, I see that the return type is Unknown. The error for await blocking_code() is the same.

Tip: Enable strict mode to see what's wrong.

Possible duplicate: How to annotate the type of a decorator of an async function in Python 3.7? (change (fn: Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]] to (fn: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]).

Please ensure that the code is posted in text format, and not as a screenshot.

Thanks to @InSync, the following seems to work:
from functools import wraps
import time
import asyncio
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")

def async_wrapper(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]:
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        print("wrapper")
        return await asyncio.to_thread(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@async_wrapper
def blocking_code():
    print("Start")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("end")
    return "a"

a = await blocking_code()

